# I cannot get TTS to speak in different language autometic. It is always speaking in English

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I want to make an application which can speak a different language, the text of which which will be written in a text field, which may be English, Bengali or any other language. I use this code but can not speak in different language. It is always speaking in English or which language I set in ***Google-Text-speech*** from phone setting.

Here is my java code

```
package com.example.texttospeech;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnClickListener {

TextToSpeech tts;
EditText input;
TextView TextCount;
Button b1, b2;
Thread thread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
      TextCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextCount);
      b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
      b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



      b1.setOnClickListener(this);
      b2.setOnClickListener(this);
      tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

      TextCountNow();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button:
        String text = input.getText().toString();

        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            String EmptyText = "Nothing found in text fild. please Write something to read.";
            tts.speak(EmptyText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (text.length() > 5000) {
            String FaildText = "Text Ought of length. Maximum length is 5000. Please remove some text and try again";
            tts.speak(FaildText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ought of length. Maximum length is 5000.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            String ReadingText = text + ". Text reading completed";
            tts.speak(ReadingText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        break;

    case R.id.button1:

        input.setText("");
        break;
    }

}


@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Locale bahasa = tts.getLanguage();
        int result = tts.setLanguage(bahasa);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This Language is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");

        } else {
            //do nathing
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "initialization faild");
    }



}


public void TextCountNow(){
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int textLanth = input.getText().length();
            TextCount.setText("" + textLanth); 
            h.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

    h.postDelayed(r, 500);
}


}
```

Comment: Google Text to Speech engine does not automatically detect the language, you have to do that in your code and then set the language accordingly.

Comment: I want to set only Bengali. How can i do?

Comment: Not many text to speech engines support Bengali, or will have the necessary files installed. You'll need to handle that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For Bengali Language :

```
@Override
            public void onInit(int i) {

                if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                    int result = textToSpeechService.setLanguage(new Locale("bn"));

                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED
                    ) {

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Speech Service Not Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                        textToSpeechService.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

                               stopBanglaReading();

                               

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(String utteranceId) {

                            }
                        });

                        int voicePitch = settings.getInt("ExplVoicePitch", 10);

                        int voiceSpeed = settings.getInt("ExplVoiceSpeed", 8);

                        textToSpeechService.setSpeechRate((float) voiceSpeed / 10);
                        textToSpeechService.setPitch((float) voicePitch / 10);
                        startSpeaking(onubad);

                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Speech Service Not Ready, Please Try Again....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }
        });
```